# Change Default Calendar on Apple Watch

Tags: calendar, siri, apple-watch

When I use Siri to create appointments on my Apple Watch, it gets dropped in my iCloud calendar. Is there a way to have this go to a different calendar? On iOS, you can find this in settings, but the watch doesn't seem to honor the setting.

Comment: Won't it honor what you have set on your iPhone's Settings -> Mail, Contacts, and Calendars -> Default Calendar?

Comment: It would appear not

Comment: Interesting. Default calendar should be automatically synced but it is one thing that isn't listed under My Watch -> Calendars. I'm not sure what to make of that.